# Removing objects from an array onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a an array of items which holds item objects. I want to create a function that when I click on a certain item it is removed from the array. I know I need to use something like splice and I have implemented the following solution but it does the seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
function updateView() {


for (var i = 0; i < storeItems.length; i++) {
    output += "<a href='#' id='itemTitle' onclick='removeRecord(" + i + ");'>" 
    + storeItems[i].title + " " + "\n" + "</a>";

   }

function removeRecord(i) {

    storeItems.splice(i, 1);
    var newItem = "";

    // re-display the records from storeItems.

    for (var i = 0; i < storeItems.length; i++) {
        newItem += "<a href='#' onclick='removeRecord(" + i + ");'>X</a> " 
        + storeItems[i] + " <br>";
    };
    document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML = newItem;
}
```

I think this the error is in the line below:

```
output  +=  "<a href='#' id='itemTitle' onclick='removeRecord(" + i + ");'>" +  storeItems[i].title + " " + "\n" + "</a>";
```

Because it does not recognise the "onclick" event even when I try to do a test with a simple alert.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong. Also if you think you need more information to answer this question please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use any indentation of your code you like, but when asking other people for help, please have the courtesy to take a moment and format the code readably into a consistent, somewhat standard form. Tools like http://jsbeautifier.org can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ...

```
storeItems = storeItems.splice(i, 1);
```

**WRONG**: Basically, you have to assign the spliced array to something.

**UODATE**:

Here's the way I would do it ... tested in **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/xpag66Lk/7/)**:

```
var storeItems = [{
    title: "Dog"
}, {
    title: "Cat"
}, {
    title: "Bird"
}];

var foods = document.getElementById('foods');
foods.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var index = e.target.getAttribute('value');
    storeItems.splice(index, 1);

    // re-display the records from storeItems.
    updateView();
});

function updateView() {
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < storeItems.length; i++) {
        output += "<a href='#' class='item' value='" + i + "'>" + storeItems[i].title + " " + "\n" + "</a>";

    }
    document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML = output;
}


updateView();
```

HTML:

```
<div id='foods'></div>
```

This effectively takes the onclick event off of the anchor tag (you could have them on any type of tag at this point) and I also reused your updateView code in the Listener so that it only needs maintained in one location.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the reply. I tried that but the issue is that the "onclick" event listener is not being called. When I click on the item I get the following error in my console. "removeRecord is not defined" its having trouble finding the remove recored function. Is my syntax okay for assigning the o'clock listener in the line below:    output  +=  "<a href='#' id='itemTitle' onclick='removeRecord(" + i + ");'>" +  storeItems[i].title + " " + "\n" + "</a>";

Comment: Complete rework is in place ... my original suggestion was wrong.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly. I just wanted to ask so I understand this, so what you did was to an onclick event listener to all the elements that are placed within the foods div? I just want to learn how you did it. Again thank you.

Comment: You've got that dead on.  Generally, my preference is to do this in jQuery for two reasons.  The code to attach the listener is easier and more intuitive AND I can attach to a higher element, but watch for an event on a lower element ... which makes dynamic creation of elements much easier to manage.